# Html link rewriting angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

> In cases like the following, links are not rewritten; instead, the browser will perform a full page reload to the original link.
>
> - Links that contain target element
>     Example: `<a href="/ext/link?a=b" target="_self">link</a>`
> - Absolute links that go to a different domain
>     Example: `<a href="http://angularjs.org/">link</a>`
> - Links starting with '/' that lead to a different base path when base is defined
>     Example: `<a href="/not-my-base/link">link</a>`

Can anybody help me with this. 
[angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location#hashbang-and-html5-modes_html5-mode_html-link-rewriting)? what is the meaning of this third point. i also dont understand the solution of normal application on the same directory

> When running Angular in the root of a domain, along side perhaps a
>   normal application in the same directory, the "otherwise" route
>   handler will try to handle all the URLs, including ones that map to
>   static files.
>
> To prevent this, you can set your base href for the app to  and then prefix links to URLs that should be handled with ..
>   Now, links to locations, which are not to be routed by Angular, are
>   not prefixed with . and will not be intercepted by the otherwise rule
>   in your $routeProvider.

Comment: @stewie here you go..